# How do I toggle a table row display?

Tags: c#, jquery

I would like to toggle my table row on an .change function in jquery.  The desired row is being displayed in this code, how do I hide the other rows at the same time?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#ddlSelect').change(function() {
      var ddlId = $('#ddlSelect').val();
      alert(ddlId);         
      //$('#displayTable').hide();
      $('#' + ddlId).show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#ddlSelect').change(function() {
      var ddlId = $('#ddlSelect').val();
      $('#displayTable tr').each( function() {
          $(this).hide();
      });
      $('#' + ddlId).show();
   });
});
```

Comment: I got it... $('#displayTable tr').each( function() {  toggles through each row.  Could you make the edit so I can credit you for the answer. Thanks!